# GPU Engine Performance Counter All Instances in VB .Net

Tags: vb.net

So I have a piece of code in my program that reports CPU usage across all cores.

`Dim cpuUsage As New PerformanceCounter("Processor", "% Processor Time", "_Total")
msgbox(cpuUsage.NextValue)`

I am trying to use the same technique to check GPU usage with the new Windows 10 Update. The problem is instead of _Total the only thing listed is all instances which I cannot seem to call in VB:

`Dim gpuUsage As New PerformanceCounter("GPU Engine", "Utilization Percentage", "<all instances>")`

That code generates an error: Instance Name not found in category